# rename filenames from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rename all upper case letters from file names to lower case letters.

my file structure

```
p:\TeSt\001-Movie.txt
p:\TeSt\002-moVie.txt
p:\TeSt\003-Pics.txt
p:\TeSt\004-KKKFLfasf.txt
```

and this is how it should look

```
p:\TeSt\001-movie.txt
p:\TeSt\002-movie.txt
p:\TeSt\003-pics.txt
p:\TeSt\004-kkkflfasf.txt
```

However, the folder should not be renamed

```
import os
path = 'p:\TeSt'
for file in os.listdir():
    os.rename(file, file.lower())
then = os.listdir()
```

but I get an error and the files are not renamed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to give the full path of the files and pass that to the rename function, it should work.

Try the below code:

```
import os

path = 'p:/TeSt/'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(path + file, path + file.lower())

then = os.listdir(path)
print(then)
```

output:

```
['001-movie.txt', '004-kkkflfasf.txt', '002-movie.txt', '003-pics.txt']
```

***NOTE:*** Forwadslash (`/`) has been used in order to avoid using (`\`) which is a special character in python. You can always replace `/` with `\\` in windows.

Comment: Note that you can use forward slashes on Windows too - all versions of Windows (and MSDOS versions that support paths - 2.0 or later) will take / as a path separator in code, just not on the command line.