# How can I capitalize file name

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that can capitalize any file name.

here is my code:

```
import os
file = os.walk("E:\Work\experiment\ex")
for root, dirs, files in file:
    fil = files[1]
    cap = fil.capitalize()
    new_name = os.renames(fil, cap)
    print(new_name)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'basic_problm_2.py' -> 'Basic_problm_2.py'
```

Comment: [rename-filenames-from-uppercase-to-lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958072/rename-filenames-from-uppercase-to-lowercase) Follow above link and just **change the lower() method with upper() method**.

Answer (score 4):

You are forgetting that `fil` is equal to the name of file. When you call `os.renames`, it looks for that file in the current directory and it doesn't find it, thus the error is raised. You have to send absolute path to the `renames` method:

```
import os
file = os.walk("E:\Work\experiment\ex")
for root, dirs, files in file:
    fil = files[1]
    cap = fil.capitalize()
    new_name = os.renames(os.path.join(root, fil), os.path.join(root, cap))
    print(new_name)
```

`os.path.join` simply joins the arguments it takes. `root` is the directory where the `fil` is, so `os.path.join(root, fil)` will give you the absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

path = "C:/foo/foo/test/"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)):
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.capitalize())
        )
```

This should do the trick. I'll also recommend using forward slash `/` with directories as backslash `\` can cause issues (Another option is you can use `//` instead).

Comment: It's working fine but I need t capitalized for specific file.